# Correct way to STOP with MPI

Tags: fortran, mpi

I'm using MPI, and at some points want to use STOP (or another method), to exit the program with an error message.

Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
STOP 'Error'
```

But I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong. Do I need to call MPI_FINALIZE first? Is there something else to be doing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a catastrophic error condition, the usual way to exit is `call MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, errcode, ierr)`.   In most implementations, this will kill all tasks.   In less drastic situations you could make sure all the tasks know of the condition and then have them all excit more gracefully with an `MPI_Finalize`.

Comment: Letting all processes know of a non-global condition would require a collective such as a broadcast, but how do the other processes know to start that? Unless you want to start tinkering with non-blocking barriers or such.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [MPI_Abort](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node175.html#SECTION00830000000000000000):

> The behavior of MPI_ABORT
>        (comm, errorcode),for comm other then MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
>        is implementation-dependent. One the other hand, **a call to 
>        MPI_ABORT(MPI_COMM_WORLD, errorcode) should always cause all 
>        processes in the group of MPI_COMM_WORLD to abort**.

Answer (score 2):

Testing this on NERSC supercomupters, I found that

```
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
stop
```

can not stop the whole program. The following works:

```
 call MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, errcode, ierr)
 stop
```

Comment: `MPI_Finalize()` is kind of a collective operation. that's why the accepted answer suggests it but only  when invoked by **all** tasks in order to complete. `MPI_Abort()` is all you need (e.g. the `stop` statement is unnecessary) if you expect one task should abort the full MPI job.

Comment: Note that rather than a NERSC issue is an Cray-MPICH issue with certain Client/Server MPI communication forms.